# Import large data (json) into Firebase periodically

Tags: firebase, architecture, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions

We are in the situation that we will have to update large amounts of data (ca. 5 Mio Records) in firebase periodically. At the moment we have a few json files that are around ~1 GB in size.

As existing third party solutions ([here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-import) and [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-streaming-import)) have some reliability issues (import object per object; or need for open connection) and are quite disconnected to the google cloud platform ecosystem. I wonder if there is now an "official" way using i.e. the new *google cloud functions*? Or a combination with *app engine* / *google cloud storage* / *google cloud datastore*.

I really like not to deal with authentication — something that cloud functions seems to handle well, but I assume the function would time out (?)

#### With the new firebase tooling available, how to:

1. Have long running cloud functions to do data fetching / inserts? (does it make sense?)
2. Get the json files into & from somewhere inside the google cloud platform?
3. Does it make sense to first throw large data into google-cloud-datastore (i.e. too $$$ expensive to store in firebase) or can the firebase real-time database be reliably treaded as a large data storage.

Comment: I've not dealt with importing large JSON files, but I can talk about processing millions of database records with Cloud Functions. I process recursively, grab a 100 records. Process them, save the last key in the DB. Start the next Cloud Function from that key, then repeat until all 1,000,000 records are processed. 

This allows me to limit my cloud functions to shorter execution times.

Comment: @sketchthat I assume you have an extra "worker db" to track whats going on (?). Do you mind sharing how long it takes for cloud functions to iterate in that approach over 1 mio records, with regard what the operation does and how large/deep your records are? That would help me a lot to estimate my architecture.

Comment: check out my gist; https://gist.github.com/sketchthat/9f2329864cec4d79faa4e66c6bcc375d

It's hard to say how long it takes because it depends how deep your objects are and what kind of processing you're doing to each item. You can play with the 100 records and make it larger / smaller to optimise your request time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally post the answer as it aligns with the new Google Cloud Platform tooling of 2017.

The newly introduced Google Cloud Functions have a limited run-time of approximately 9 minutes ([540 seconds](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas)). However, cloud functions are able to create a node.js read stream from cloud storage like so ([@googlecloud/storage on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage))

```js
var gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({
// You don't need extra authentication when running the function
// online in the same project
  projectId: 'grape-spaceship-123',
  keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'
});

// Reference an existing bucket. 
var bucket = gcs.bucket('json-upload-bucket');

var remoteReadStream = bucket.file('superlarge.json').createReadStream();
```

Even though it is a remote stream, it is highly efficient. In tests I was able to parse jsons larger than 3 GB under 4 minutes, doing simple json transformations.

As we are working with node.js streams now, any JSONStream Library can efficiently transform the data on the fly ([JSONStream on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream)), dealing with the data asynchronously just like a large array with event streams ([event-stream on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-stream)).

```js
es = require('event-stream')

remoteReadStream.pipe(JSONStream.parse('objects.*'))
  .pipe(es.map(function (data, callback(err, data)) {
    console.error(data)
    // Insert Data into Firebase.
    callback(null, data) // ! Return data if you want to make further transformations.
  }))
```

Return only null in the callback at the end of the pipe to prevent a memory leak blocking the whole function.

If you do heavier transformations that require a longer run time, either use a "job db" in firebase to track where you are at and only do i.e. 100.000 transformations and call the function again, or set up an additional function which listens on inserts into a "forimport db" that finally transforms the raw jsons object record into your target format and production system asynchronously. Splitting import and computation.

Additionally, you can run cloud functions code in a nodejs app engine. But not necessarily the other way around.

Comment: n00b question... all I want to do is read the entire large json object from the file into a javascript object in memory... No need for any special filtering, parsing or event streams... How do I do that?

Comment: It takes eons for my read stream to complete even though my json file is only 82 MB. How can this be?

Comment: I am trying to read stream a 512 MB GCS file and stream insert into Bigquery, but it's throwing me Heap out of memory issue. Can you please explain what was your approach for processing 3gb file?

Comment: That sounds like you have a memory leak in your code. I.e. the 3GB large file was a .json (mostly geo data). As written in the answer, I used a stream library that works with the json of that large file chunk for chunk. So the whole file has never been on the functions process. I think yours crashes because you try to load 512MB into the functions mode.js process - or processing it in a way that hinders the js garbe collector to free memory (memory leak). You need to make sure that you just use streams.

Comment: So the flow is really simple, I've around 512 mb xml (70k records), convert it in objects, stream insert in bigquery in 100 - 200 rows. Do you think this whole job can be performed inside a Google Cloud function?