# How do I import this large JSON into a Firestore database, using Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a large JSON file (around 110MB). I am trying to import it into my Firestore database to be used within my React application. How would I go about doing this?

I have already tried using this code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceaccount.json');
const datafile = './DIID.json';
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://databaseurl.firebaseio.com"
});

const runtimeOpts = {
  timeoutSeconds: 540,
  memory: '2GB'
};

exports.setData = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, () => {
        return admin.database().ref('Destiny').push(datafile)
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Done");
            })
    })
});
```

But my function always times out after the specified 540 seconds and there is no data written to the database.

Here is an example of my JSON structure:

```
"423789": {
        "displayProperties": {
            "description": "PARADISE LOST: A group of castaways seek to overthrow the divine order.",
            "name": "Mythos Hack 4.1",
            "icon": "/common/destiny2_content/icons/47849b754551cc0f4f03acd7554882eb.jpg",
            "hasIcon": true
        },
        "collectibleHash": 4220193450,
        "backgroundColor": {
            "colorHash": 0,
            "red": 0,
            "green": 0,
            "blue": 0,
            "alpha": 0
        },
        "screenshot": "/common/destiny2_content/screenshots/423789.jpg",
        "itemTypeDisplayName": "Gauntlets",
        "uiItemDisplayStyle": "",
        "itemTypeAndTierDisplayName": "Rare Gauntlets",
        "displaySource": "",
        "action": {
            "verbName": "Dismantle",
            "verbDescription": "",
            "isPositive": false,
            "requiredCooldownSeconds": 0,
            "requiredItems": [],
            "progressionRewards": [],
            "actionTypeLabel": "shard",
            "rewardSheetHash": 0,
            "rewardItemHash": 0,
            "rewardSiteHash": 0,
            "requiredCooldownHash": 0,
            "deleteOnAction": true,
            "consumeEntireStack": false,
            "useOnAcquire": false
        }
}
```

This is repeated over and over again for lots of different items.

I have tried using a real-time database but the file size exceeds the maximum quota for file sizes, and I have also tried various parser's to periodically write the file to the database but I couldn't seem to get that working either.

Here are links to some things I have tried so far:

https://bigcodenerd.org/import-export-data-firestore/

[Import large data (json) into Firebase periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398442/import-large-data-json-into-firebase-periodically?rq=1)

Any help will be appreciated, if there is a better solution to my issue I am willing to change it up and approach it differently.

Comment: Did you try to load the JSON in memory and to push each object one by one ? Is it fit in the max 9min of timeout?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have tried to push it line by line before but not object by object, how would I achieve this? The max timeout is set to 9 minutes but so far everything I have tried always hits the timeout, I am not sure if I am performing each action correctly

Comment: In fact, I don't know the structure of your file. Is it a full JSON of 110Mo? If yes, object are independents? Is it a line separated JSON ? The idea is to split the process. If you can make chunk of 50 objects (for example), it will be easy to parallelize the processing.